# last row in gridview not reaching rowCommand code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview with rowCommand set to one of the columns. Everything is working ok but I get this strange bug for every last row in the gridview. The RowCommand block doesn't executes. All the other rows work except the last one. If I sort the grid view and the last row comes on top it works OK, but what ever row then comes at the bottom, again not working.

```
<asp:GridView id="gvSchedules" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="odsSchedules" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" EmptyDataText="gvSchedules"
OnRowCommand="gvSchedules_RowCommand" CssSelectorClass="NormalGridView"
EnableViewState="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="ScheduleName" HeaderText="gvSchedulesName">
        <ItemStyle Width="100%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:hyperlink id="lnkEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# EditUrl("ScheduleID", Eval("ScheduleID").ToString(), "edit", "SpaceID=" + PanelSecurity.PackageId) %>'>
                <%# PortalAntiXSS.Encode((string)Eval("ScheduleName")) %>
            </asp:hyperlink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="ScheduleTypeID" HeaderText="gvSchedulesType"
        ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# GetSharedLocalizedString("ScheduleType." + Eval("ScheduleTypeID").ToString()) %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NextRun" SortExpression="NextRun" HeaderText="gvSchedulesNextRun"
        ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastRun" SortExpression="LastRun" HeaderText="gvSchedulesLastRun"
        ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="gvSchedulesStatus" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdStart" runat="server" ToolTip="Start" SkinID="StartMedium" Visible='<%# !IsScheduleActive((int)Eval("StatusID")) %>'
                CommandName="start" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScheduleID") %>' />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdStop" runat="server" ToolTip="Stop" SkinID="StopMedium" Visible='<%# IsScheduleActive((int)Eval("StatusID")) %>'
                CommandName="stop" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScheduleID") %>' />
            <%# GetScheduleStatus((int)Eval("StatusID")) %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="gvSchedulesResult" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# GetAuditLogRecordSeverityName((int)Eval("LastResult"))%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="PackageName" HeaderText="gvSchedulesSpace">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:hyperlink id="lnkSpace" runat="server"
                NavigateUrl='<%# GetSpaceHomePageUrl((int)Eval("PackageID")) %>'>
                <%# Eval("PackageName") %>
            </asp:hyperlink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Username" HeaderText="gvSchedulesUser">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:hyperlink id="lnkUser" runat="server"
                NavigateUrl='<%# GetUserHomePageUrl((int)Eval("UserID")) %>'>
                <%# Eval("Username") %>
            </asp:hyperlink>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<div class="GridFooter">
    <asp:Label ID="lblScheduledTasks" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblScheduledTasks" Text="Scheduled Tasks:"></asp:Label>
    <uc4:Quota ID="quotaTasks" runat="server" QuotaName="OS.ScheduledTasks" />
</div>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSchedules" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="GetSchedulesPagedCount"
    SelectMethod="GetSchedulesPaged" SortParameterName="sortColumn" TypeName="WebsitePanel.Portal.SchedulesHelper" OnSelected="odsSchedules_Selected">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="chkRecursive" Name="recursive" PropertyName="Checked" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchBox" Name="filterColumn" PropertyName="FilterColumn" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchBox" Name="filterValue" PropertyName="FilterValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and my serverside code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("zarejdame stranitsata <br />");
            //BindServerTime();

            // set display preferences
            gvSchedules.PageSize = UsersHelper.GetDisplayItemsPerPage();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                chkRecursive.Visible = (PanelSecurity.EffectiveUser.Role != UserRole.User);
                // toggle controls
                //btnAddItem.Enabled = PackagesHelper.CheckGroupQuotaEnabled(
                 //   PanelSecurity.PackageId, ResourceGroups.Statistics, Quotas.STATS_SITES);

                searchBox.AddCriteria("ScheduleName", GetLocalizedString("Text.ScheduleName"));
                searchBox.AddCriteria("Username", GetLocalizedString("Text.Username"));
                searchBox.AddCriteria("FullName", GetLocalizedString("Text.FullName"));
                searchBox.AddCriteria("Email", GetLocalizedString("Text.Email"));

                bool isUser = PanelSecurity.SelectedUser.Role == UserRole.User;
                gvSchedules.Columns[gvSchedules.Columns.Count - 1].Visible = !isUser;
                gvSchedules.Columns[gvSchedules.Columns.Count - 2].Visible = !isUser;
                Response.Write("page load za parvi pat<br />");
            }

            Response.Write("krai na page load<br />");
        }

protected void odsSchedules_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                ProcessException(e.Exception);
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }

protected void gvSchedules_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("1111");
        Response.Write("aaaa " + e.CommandArgument + "<br />");
        int scheduleId = Utils.ParseInt(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), 0);
        if (e.CommandName == "start")
        {
            Response.Write("start schedule<br />");
            try
            {
                int result = ES.Services.Scheduler.StartSchedule(scheduleId);
                if (result < 0)
                {
                    ShowResultMessage(result);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowErrorMessage("SCHEDULE_START_TASK", ex);
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "stop")
        {
            try
            {
                int result = ES.Services.Scheduler.StopSchedule(scheduleId);
                if (result < 0)
                {
                    ShowResultMessage(result);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowErrorMessage("SCHEDULE_STOP_TASK", ex);
                return;
            }
        }

        // rebind grid
        gvSchedules.DataBind();
    }
```

I dont have anything in my PageLoad. By debuging I can see that the input fires a postback for the last row and it reaches the pageload but never gets to the rowCommand code block. The Response.Write("1111"); never shows up. Any idea will be helpfull.

Comment: Are you hooking up the GridView to the gvSchedules_RowCommand event in the markup, or in code?

Comment: How are you binding your data?

Comment: I use ObjectDataSource to populate the grid and yes in the markup I have the RowCommand Event.. like I said the other rows are working with there RowCommand, just the last row doesn't..

Comment: Can you post the rest of your markup including your ObjectDataSource and the GridView definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `OnRowCommand="gvSchedules_RowCommand"` on your gridview

Comment: I allready have added it, otherwise the other rows RowCommand wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem and I got the reason for it. Your problem might have been solved but I am writing it here as it might help someone else who tumbles in to same situation.

The onrowcommand event associates itself with the rowindex of the grid which helps in tracking which row was clicked.

If any headers or rows are added to the grid after binding the data, then the row indexes get changed and rowcommand will execute only for those rows where it found the index.

In my case I added a header and the rowindex was offset by one. This was the reason it could not find a rowcommand control on last row. May be this is problem in your case too.

To solve it, add your headers during onrowcreated event, this will not mess up the row indexes.